# If $P(x,y)$ is a point on or inside of $x^2+y^2 \le 1$, where does the point $Q(x+y, xy)$ exist?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A high school math question:

> If $P(x,y)$ is a point on or inside of $x^2+y^2 \le 1$, where does the point $Q(x+y, xy)$ exist?  Show the region where point $Q$ exists and find the area of the region.
> My approach: let $x+y=X, xy=Y$. I want to know the relation between $X$ and $Y$
> based on the given inequality. Since $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy$, I can write $X^2-2Y\leq1$. According to answer key, since $x, y$ are real numbers, $x,y$ can be considered as two roots of the quadratic equation $t^2-Xt+Y=0$ and so discriminant
> $X^2-4Y\geq0$ should be satisfied. My question is that in the beginning, $(x,y)$ is point from $x^2+y^2\leq1$ so they are both real numbers.  If x, y are real numbers, $x+y, xy$ must be also real numbers.  Then why do I have to go back and satisfy real numbers requirement for $x$ and $y$ after $X^2-2Y\leq1$?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. And use this to write the math formulas: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I added what i have tried. please reopen this question.

Comment: Please format your post, using the link above.

Comment: You understand that $X,Y$ must satisfy $X^2-2Y\leq1.$ Here are numbers that satisfy this equation: $X=0,$ $Y=1.$ What are the values of $x$ and $y$ that make $X=0$ and $Y=1$? Are they real numbers? So how can $Q(0,1)$ be inside the region you are seeking? That is why you need to "go back" and find an additional inequality to ensure that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. Actually you have that requirement even before you know that $(x,y)$ is inside the circle.

Comment: I understand your point.  question: how do we find the "additional inequality" to ensure that x, y are real numbers if the transformation is different ? for example, X=1/x, Y=1/y or X=1/(2x+1), Y=y^2  and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the point $P$ has coordinates $(a,b)$. Since $P$ is either on or inside $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$.
Now $Q$ has coordinates $(a+b,ab)$. Our goal is to see how the coordinates of $Q$ are related to each other. We start with the original inequality and manipulate:
$$a ^2 + b^2 \leq 1 \\
\implies a ^2 + 2ab + b^2 \leq 2ab + 1\\
\implies (a+b)^2 \leq 2ab + 1\\$$
So if we relabel $Q's$ coordinates to say $(p,q)$ where $p=a+b,q=ab$, then we see that $p^2 \leq 2q+1$
So $Q$ lies on the boundary or the interior of the region $x^2 \leq 2y + 1 $

Edit:
Also we have that since
$$(a-b)^2 \geq0 \\
\implies a^2 + 2ab +b^2 \geq4ab\\
\implies (a+b)^2 \geq 4ab$$
so another boundary curve is $x^2 \geq 4y$. Together, you're looking at the region (and the interior)
$$4y \leq x^2 \leq 2y+1$$

Comment: what is the reason behind the inequality (a-b)^2>=0 ? why do we have to use this inequality?

Comment: @user138819 The reason the inequality holds is cuz squaring something results in a nonnegative answer. But if the motivation behind this isn't obvious, I'll provide a different angle to think of this step. We want to find how the quantities $a+b$ and $ab$ are related. A natural inequality that pops up all over mathematics that related sums of numbers with their products is the [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) inequality, which (after some algebraic manipulation) yields the same inequality I wrote.

Comment: But AM-GM inequality holds true only when a and b are both  non-negative numbers.

Comment: That's only if you consider the form $a+b\geq 2\sqrt{ab}$. The version $(a+b)^2 \geq 4ab$ works for $a,b$ arbitrary

Answer (score 2):

The inequation $X^2-2Y\le1$ does not guarantee the existence of real numbers $x,y$ such that $X=x+y$ and $Y=xy.$

What you (correctly) proved is only that *if such real numbers exist* then they satisfy $x^2+y^2\le1$ iff $X,Y$ satisfy $X^2-2Y\le1$ (this, because $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy$).

The condition (for the existence of real numbers $x,y$ such that $X=x+y$ and $Y=xy$) is $X^2-4Y\ge0$ (by the proof you reproduced in your post and seem to have understood).

So, a point $(X,Y)$ corresponds to some $P$ in the disc iff it satisfies *both* inequations: $X^2-4Y\ge0$ and $X^2-2Y\le1.$

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a symmetric condition on $x$, $y$. Surely you can translate it into a condition for $x+y$, $x y$. That is somehow the point of the exercise.

The hint is: the [region between two curves](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ContourPlot%5B%7Ba%5E2-4b%3D%3D0%2Ca%5E2-2b%3D%3D1%7D%2C%7Ba%2C-2%2C2%7D%2C%7Bb%2C-2%2C2%7D%5D)